# Can't Access "Data" in the XML Data structure: <Name Attributes> Data </Name>

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

i need to Access the "Data" in the following XML Data structure:

`<Name Attributes> Data </Name>`

With the normal Python Parsing `.attrib` i can only Access the "Attributes" but i need the "Data".

Do you know what this Data structure means and how i can Access the "Data" with Python.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your example, it should be `name.text` or you want to assign new value for this `name.text = "new Data"`

Example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("some-random-file")
parent = tree.getroot()

name = parent.find(".//name")
name.text = "new Data"
```

[Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file)